# Getting sub types in Typescript

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, if I have an interface like this:

```
export interface IMyInterface {
    category: "Primary" | "Secondary" | "Tertiary",
}
```

Is it possible to access the individual "sub types" of the category, e.g. "Primary" (like one could with an enum), so that I can use them for a comparison?

What I am looking for is something like the following (does *not* work):

```
typeof(
    myVariableWhichImplementsIMyInterface.category
).Primary;
```

Comment: After knowing that category it is, are you going to do different actions based on different categories?

Comment: @khewdev Yes, that's the plan.

Comment: As asked this is impossible.  Interfaces are [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) so there's nothing at runtime you can index into here.  If you want the string literal `"Primary"` you need to write it out yourself.  Note that writing `xxx.Primary` vs `"Primary"` is essentially the same in terms of effort, so if the latter is unacceptable could you [edit] to explain?  I'm happy to write up an answer but right now the answer is essentially "no", so maybe there's some nuance I'm missing?

Comment: @jcalz No real nuance. I'm only asking because doing it as shown in my code example is less effort than creating a separate enum for it. It seems strange that one can create a type like this, but not have access to its values later. VSCode knows that `category` can only be one of those three values, so I was just wondering if there is a way to access that knowledge.

Comment: I haven't done a deep dive to verify, but could this be a situation in which [tagged union types](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/tagged-union-types-in-typescript) could be used?

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces don't persist in code so you can't use `typeof` to query an interface, unfortunately. You have a few options available to you but none of them are really what you're truly looking for.

Use an enum for your categories. Not strictly necessary but is available in code.

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAwghgF2AcwPYCcCeUDeAoKQqAIgAd0BLCOLYqAXhIAVLraAaAo4gZ2AGNUIACY1MdRsQDKAoaI5dCxJOgQUxEkgBVgq9bTwBfPHgSZSwWIhQZMAVRAUhDKAAMAJDnhI0WQ64BuEwoQFQAzOH5LAEkAWUxo0N0IqNxFKH5rX0wALisfWyMTQRAeBCgITAAxMBB%20FwAKTIKsPO8bLCgAH3yO%200dnAEoGAD40ogyhHlQAG2AAOhnUZCas20Gg4zxKmrqG9uz58ioxDe3q2v4G4hYT2kGgA)

```
enum Category {
    "primary" = "Primary",
    "secondary" = "Secondary",
    "tertiary" = "Tertiary"
}

interface IMyInterface {
    category: Category
}

if (someObj.category === Category.primary) {
    // do something
}
```

If you need a union type of categories

```
type CategoryUnion = ${Category}
```

You could use a plain object instead of an enum. Unfortunately either way your categories will need to be available in the codebase not just types for you to compare against.

Answer (score -1):

To extract the type use:

```
type Category = IMyInterface['category']
```

For your purpose I would recommend just using a switch statement:

```
switch (variable.category) {
  case 'Primary': {
    // functionality here
    break;
  }
}
```

If your typescript is set up correctly it will do type checking and compiler errors when misspelled.

To the best of my knowledge you cannot get eg `'Primary'` by using typeof.

Comment: I get an error in my comparison: "... only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here". It doesn't let me access e.g. `.Primary`, so I guess that's what causing the error mentioned. Also, this uses a string, so is subject to typos.

Comment: I agree that this answer does not work for your use case, but I don't see how it's subject to typos, given that you will get a compiler error if you misspell it.